# Is the beamforming result described by this matlab code useful?

Tags: adaptive-filters, beamforming, array-signal-processing, adaptive-algorithms

A narrow-band beamformer for $0$ degree in the frequency domain is created for $8$ sensors and compared with a usual delay and sum beamformer. The question can also be expressed as : can we have better beamforming solution by "masking the desired spatial frequency band"  to our usual beamforming result?

A beamformer create a weight vector and performs dot product with every spatial i.e. array wise, received vector to allow signal from a desired direction and suppress others. In delay and sum beamformer the weights are calculated based on the expected delay from the desired angle. In the code below delay and sum beamformer weight is given by the variable name delaySumWeights. Further, the code simulates received signal from -180 to 180 degress and compare the performance of the delay and sum beamformer and the other beamformer.

The process of the algorithm is not given but can anyone please check and verify if such an algorithm is useful. I understand that how the algorithm does it, is not given, but can't one understand it's usefulness from knowing what it does?  The question has only a few MATLAB lines and a graph. The code of the MATLAB file *testVer.m* is not given.

```matlab
clear();
close('all');
clc();

noOfSensors = 8;
f = 8e3;
distanceBetweenSensors = 15/1000;
velocityWave = 340;
angles=-2*pi*f(1)*[0:noOfSensors-1]*distanceBetweenSensors/velocityWave;
diR=cos(angles)+1j*sin(angles);
delaySumWeights=diR/noOfSensors;
theta = -pi:pi/50:pi;
scanningMatrix = zeros(noOfSensors,length(theta));
for I=1:length(theta)
    scanningMatrix(:,I) = exp(-j*2*f*pi*[0:noOfSensors-1]'*distanceBetweenSensors*cos(theta(I))/velocityWave);
end

ampli = (((rand+1j*rand)));
ampli = ampli/abs(ampli);
phaseOfSource = ampli*eye(length(theta));

receivedSignal = scanningMatrix*phaseOfSource;

yValuesTestHat=testVer(receivedSignal);

[cc,rr]=size(receivedSignal);

for k=1:rr
    delaySum(k)=conj(delaySumWeights)*(receivedSignal(:,k));
end
figure
hold on
plot(theta,(abs(yValuesTestHat.*delaySum)))

plot(theta,(abs(delaySum)))
grid on
legend('New','delaySum')
title('Comparison')
```

[image]

I appreciate any comments.

Comment: I don't think this is a `soft-question`.  We have to decode your code.  I dunno why the `phaseOfSource` is scrambled.  Is it because you can't count on phase-coherent superposition of all of the sources?  I thought that's how phased arrays work.  Based on their phase offsets between adjacent sources at an angle offa dead center.  And I don't know what `testVer` is nor `yValuesTestHat` is.

Comment: i can't tell if it has value.  i don't sufficiently understand it.

Comment: Well, as @robertbristow-johnson commented, it's not much we could say about the question. To be honest, I am not sure I even understand the question. Do you want us to comment on your algorithm (this is not a forum site), do you want to find errors in your algorithm (not given), or what? If the question is just "is this algorithm any useful", then the answer may be, "it is as useful as a spatial filter (aka beamformer) is". That means that it may be useful for certain situations but this is very context and application dependent 'cause we don't know the drawbacks of the algorithm.

Comment: Well, I guess anyone who is interested in spatial filters. This would definitely include people who are into *Sound-Field Analysis* (Ambisonics, Directional Audio Coding - DiRAC, Sound Field Measurements and Characterisation), *Sound Reproduction* (Immersive Audio, Cross-Talk Cancellation - CTC),  *Sonar* and *Radar* applications (military included), *Telecommunications* (5G, 6G) and *Antennas*. I may of course be missing a lot of fields that could benefit but I believe you get an idea

Comment: @hyrt not really. Since I do not know anything about the algorithm I couldn't even try to suggest someone specific. That being said, I don't think I do have anyone who's considered to be an expert in Beamforming technology in mind, so I think I'm not the right person to ask about it.

Comment: @hyrt As already mentioned, I'm not an expert in the field but I believe that narrowband beamformers are already being used in radar and telecommunication applications. Don't take my word on that but I'm sure there's quite some applications for narrowband beamformers. Additionally, the algorithm may be able to perform similarly in many different frequencies in parallel which effectively makes it wideband in a sense.

Comment: The ultimate test for a beamformer is if it will maintain both wideband performance (manifests as pointing angle error and gain loss) and if it will achieve the SNR gain expected. A generic wideband beamformer using N elements, all else being equal, should achieve an N gain of SNR at the output of the beamformer considering antenna gain and pointing angle. This is "good".

Comment: Also, keep in mind the thinking between a general beamformer and narrowband beamforming. The most robust beamformer will use true time delay techniques. Narrowband beamformers using phase shifts simply approximate this.

Comment: @Envidia If you have a substantive comment that you submit as an answer, I'll upvote. My standards are low.

Comment: The supplied script is as useful as the resolution it may achieve detecting and solving close targets in space. Having said this, without supplying complete code one cannot tell any further, hence the question as it's been posed needs further clarification in the shape of the support function testVer that seems to be pivotal to the complete performance of the supplied script in the question yet after all these comments function testVer still remains unknown to readers.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I would love to but unfortunately I'm not sure when I can get to this. I have been running out of free time lately.

Comment: @JohnBofarull, The whole idea of the question is as following: Using regular (FIR) method, the resolution / SNR Amplification of the array is limited (Basically by the windows function the array creates as shown by the Sinc function in the plot). If I have algorithm which makes the array equivalent of the plotted blue window, is it useful? You don't need the algorithm to say so. You need to understand what's the given windows might solve in practical applications.

Comment: @Royi I'm actually still curious what the hidden function does and how well it preserves SNR. The plot is normalized so it doesn't really tell me of its absolute performance vs a normal narrowband beamformer. Speaking of which, I doubt this handles wideband waveforms, which is another consideration and has its new set of problems.

Comment: Please don't effectively vandalize your question. It's fair to remove that "EDIT" (which you could maybe reformulate instead), not everything else.

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to do that, but you can't do it yourself when there's an upvoted answer, and deleting would mean removing 500 bounty, so unlikely mods will approve of it either. I see nothing wrong with this question. If you have further issues, ping a moderator or [ask on Meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Envidia, Well, indeed. But question was, given it is a black box, how can I be sure it is viable? You can answer that regardless of knowing it.

Comment: No trouble caused that way.

Comment: @hyrt Would you mind posting what the values of `yValuesTestHat` are?

Comment: @hyrt You're plotting a modified version of the `delaySum` response, not the output of `testVer` directly.

Comment: huh, did you find a button that generates a new default profile icon? Your icon looks different.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Dear OverLordGoldDragon, I did not notice it. Now I see it. I did nothing and not sure how it changed. Only thing I know is that I want to delete this question, but do not want the bounty to be taken off. Let the bounty earner have is bounty and delete this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the context of beamforming we have 2 main tasks:

- Estimate angle of arrival.
- Filter a certain range of angles (Assume connected set).

The quality of both operations depends on the ability to have sharp "windows".
Since uniform arrays are equivalent of uniform DFT we can basically talk about the resolution in frequency domain.

If you created a windows with such a sharp edges you certainly did something valuable.

For instance, in the context of communication or RADAR, it means you improved the SNR greatly and mitigate the options to apply jamming.

With iterative policy it can also be used for angle detection so it can be useful in those applications as well. Something like detecting targets in RADARS and such.

If your method is also simple and efficient, in a manner it can be implemented on edge devices, it will be something many will pay a lot for (I have some similar algorithms which were generous with me :-)). In case you can show it works and robust in real life. For instance, it doesn't require the array to be almost perfectly calibrated.

What you'd need to do is sensitivity analysis:

1. Check for different angles.
2. Check performance for different SNR.
3. Check performance for colored noise.
4. Check performance in the case of multiple signals from different angles.

The better it generalizes in those cases, the more worthful it is.

Comment: I'd be happy for a feedback from the one who -1.